# Usage of Parev Vs Parve

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food

I see some kosher items that on the kosher label it is written Parve where as others Parev. In Hebrew, we say Parve. What is the source for Parev? Why are there 2 slightly different words for indicating the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parev#English):

> In Yiddish, פּאַרעוו‎ (*parev*) is the [predicative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/predicative) form and פּאַרעווע‎ (*pareve*) the [attributive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attributive) form of the adjective. Some speakers familiar with Yiddish use this distribution in English as well, e.g. *My mom made a **pareve** casserole* but *This casserole is **parev***.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parev):

> In Yiddish, פּאַרעוו‎ (parev) is the predicative form and פּאַרעווע‎ (pareve) the attributive form of the adjective.
>
> Some speakers familiar with Yiddish use this distribution in English as well, e.g. *My mom made a pareve casserole* but *This casserole is parev*.

Comment: This answer looks familiar...